# Where does ASP.NET 5 / MVC6 store uploaded files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, temporary-files

If I upload a file and it's represented by a `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.Internal.FormFile`, will it have been stored anywhere on the filesystem of the process, or does it point to bytes that simply exist in memory?

Comment: No. It streams to memory. It's not persisted.

Comment: Love it, do you happen to have any decent source for that for a formal answer?  Feel free to submit one if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormFile object based on HttpRequest.Body memory stream. See more details on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dfe2d414376972a84b97acdca4ade84341bd24d4/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http/Features/FormFeature.cs)

```
var file = new FormFile(_request.Body, section.BaseStreamOffset.Value, section.Body.Length, name, fileName)
{
    Headers = new HeaderDictionary(section.Headers),
};
```

You can call FormFile.SaveAs() or FormFile.SaveAsAsync() to save file in filesystem:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IHostingEnvironment Hosting { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IFormFile file)
    {
        await file.SaveAsAsync(Path.Combine(Hosting.WebRootPath, "storage", "file.txt"));
        //...
    }
}
```